# Relational Algebra Filtering Results of a query

Tags: database, relational-algebra

Looking for some help solving an exercise using relational algebra, the table schema is as follows:

STUDENT(Ssn, Name, Major, Bdate)

COURSE(Course#, Cname, Dept)

ENROLL(Ssn, Course#, Quarter, Grade)

BOOK_ADOPTION(Course#, Quarter, Book_isbn)

TEXT(Book_isbn, Book_title, Publisher, Author)

The question which I am trying to solve is:

Retrieve the names of departments that adopt textbooks published by
Addison-Wesley only.

I cannot figure out how I can filter the result so that if I have a course which has switched to a book that is not published by Addison-Wesley any more.

I really appreciate all of the help!

Comment: Is the goal to figure out all courses that used to have a book published by addison-wesley and now do not, or is it simply to find all that *current* have a book that was published by addison-wesley?

Comment: The way I understand the problem is to find the department names that have only used books by that publisher. So if a department has used only books by that publisher. If a department switched the book to a different publisher it is not to appear in the final result relation. That is the part that trips me up if a the dept switched the book it still appears in my result because they used a book published by the publisher before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Renzo, I have found the answer!

1. Find all of the books not published by 'Addison-Wesley'
2. Join the resulting relation in step 1 with Book_Adoption and Course, and project on department - this will give all departments that have used a book that was not published by 'Addison-Wesley'
3. Take the Course table and project on department to get all possible departments
4. Subtract relation in step 3 - relation in step 2

π Course.Dept (Course) - (π Course.Dept (((σ Text.Publisher ≠ 'Addison-Wesley' (Text)) ⨝ Book_Adoption) ⨝ Course))

I tested this answer with relational algebra calculator and gives the desired result!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the query, it is no clear to me if it refers to all the books ever adopted or the book adopted in the current quarter.

Considering the first possibily, that is all the books ever adopted, here is the sketch of a possible solution:

1. Find the relation R(Dept, Book_isbn) that lists for all the departments the books adopted in any course, in any quarter.
2. Find the relation S(Book_isbn) of all the books published by Addison-Wesley.
3. Then, using a single algebraic operator (which?), you can obtain the result.

In the second case, at the step 1 restrict the list to all the books adopted in the course of the current quarter.

Comment: The way I understand it is, the output needs to be departments that have used only books that were published by Addison-Wesley. So if at any point a department used a book that was not published by Addison-Wesley it should not appear in the output relation. The question does not say anything about the quarter so I do not restrict it at all.